# Finding and printing most common value within MySql database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I currently have the code to retrieve values, but I don't know how to return the modal value in this array.

```
$stuff = "SELECT COUNT (SubjectNo) FROM SubjectAllocation";
$direct = mysqli_query($link, $stuff);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($direct)){
    echo $row['COUNT (SubjectNo)'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

I understand this is just performing a count, but I want to define a base to start from.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one method for getting the "mode" -- the statistical term for the most common value:

```
select subjectno
from subjectallocation
group by subjectno
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: His code works in MySQL with no 'math' required in PHP.